# PHP using array_unique and then converting to JSON, without the indexes

Tags: php, json

I am querying my DB, looping through the results and then converting to JSON.
I am also using array_unique function.

The problem is my JSON file includes the indexes, how can I return in JSON format without the indexes?
I need it this way as I am then planning to feed the JSON array directly into an apexcharts.js chart.

Here is my code:

```
$month = [];
$value = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    
    $month[] = $row['Source'];
    $value[] = $row['Days_To_Report'];
}
$month1 = array_unique($month);
$month_json = json_encode($month1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$fp = fopen('value.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $month_json);
fclose($fp);
```

And here is the JSON output:

```
{
    "0": "CGI Insurance",
    "4": "THIRD PARTY CAPTURE - CGI"
}
```

What I need is this:

```
{
    "CGI Insurance",
    "THIRD PARTY CAPTURE - CGI"
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: you need [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: Unrelated but `file_put_contents` is a lot easier to use than open, write, close.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? And show us your current SQL query attempt.